# ARM NEON: What's the difference between vld4_f32 and vld4q_f32?

Tags: memory, assembly, arm, neon, cpu-registers

I'm not in a position to make out the difference between `vld4_f32` and `vld4q_f32` in ARM NEON instructions.

The confusion started when I raised my coding levels and started looking at the assembly instructions rather than the less informative intrinsics.

The reason I need to use **vld4** variant instruction here is because, I would like to capture **4** `float32_t`'s from every **4th position** of my large array.

[image]

The `vld4_f32` intrinsics and the corresponding assembly instructions look like this ([From this link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html))

```
float32x2x4_t vld4_f32 (const float32_t *) 
Form of expected instruction(s): vld4.32 {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [r0]
```

The `vld4q_f32` intrinsics and its corresponding assembly instructions looks like this

```
float32x4x4_t vld4q_f32 (const float32_t *) 
Form of expected instruction(s): vld4.32 {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [r0]
```

Well, at the intrinsics level **the difference I see is the return type**, but if I look at the assembly instruction and the number of registers, they both look like the same. How will the compiler or the assembler know the difference between the two?

Can somebody clarify more on this and also explain how I can achieve loading **4 float32_t** values which are positioned **at every 4th memory location** into a single register?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I found out the difference. I used CodeSourcery to see the actual register contents for all the load instructions. The link I have posted doesn't give the complete details on the vld4q_f32.

Okay, first comes the `vld4_f32`, this loads **4 d** registers (e.g. d16-19) each **d** register is 64 bits long, so this instruction will load the first 8 values interleaved with an interval of 4 as shown in the figure below.
[image]

In the second case the `vld4q_f32`, this loads **8 d** registers (e.g. d16-23) instead of four. For a reader of this [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html), it is not at all clear that 8 registers will be loaded. When  I looked at the dis-assembled code for a `vld4qf32`, it was making use of 8 d registers.

This instruction will indeed do what I was hoping it to do i.e. to load 4 `float32_t` values which are at the interval of 4 as shown in the figure below.
[image]

Comment: Well, vld4q loads 4 q registers, as the name implies…

Answer (score 2):

I have disassembled two intrinsics, maybe it helps to someone:

```
// C++
uint32x4x4_t r = vld4q_u32( ( uint32_t *) output );
// assembly
VLD4.32         {D16,D18,D20,D22}, [R0]!
VLD4.32         {D17,D19,D21,D23}, [R0]

// C++
uint32x2x4_t r = vld4_u32( ( uint32_t *) output );
// assembly
VLD4.32         {D20-D23}, [R0]
```